# How to change border thickness in Qtablewidget via Pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5, border, qt-designer, thickness

I want to change specifically second and third column line's thickness in my Qtablewidget. I searched all the Internet but couldn't find a way to do it via Pyqt5. It is possible to do it with C++. If you know, I would be appreciated